# MainActivty isn't starting on Nougat and Oreo

Tags: java, android, android-layout

When running the app in Android 9 device (Lineage OS 16) it works without any problem. But when I try to open it on devices like Nougat or Oreo it just shows blank white activity. (**NOTE : I got this white blank screen only for 1 or 2 secs in Android 9 (Lineage OS) but in Nougat and Oreo it got stuck at blank white screen**). I tried launching other activities as Launcher Activity and others worked but MainActivity class should be launched to other activities work properly. I don't know whether the error is in Layout design or in Java class (I think the error may not be in Java class since the app works perfectly on Android 9 device!!). Here I provided the xml layout and Java class.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_ads"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/track_info"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/track_info_layout_height"
            android:layout_above="@+id/ll_ads">
            <LinearLayout
                android:background="@color/bottom_control_background"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/artwork_min"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4.0dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/default_artwork"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/album_artwork" />
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:padding="@dimen/content_padding"
                    android:layout_width="0.0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0">
                    <TextView
                        android:textSize="16.0sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:id="@+id/song_title"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
                    <TextView
                        android:textSize="14.0sp"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:id="@+id/song_artist"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4.0dip"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/song_title" />
                </RelativeLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/quick_controls"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/quick_prev"
                        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/btn_prev"
                        android:scaleType="center"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/prev" />
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/quick_play_pause_toggle"
                        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/btn_play"
                        android:scaleType="center"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/play" />
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/quick_next"
                        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/btn_next"
                        android:scaleType="center"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/next" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <com.musicplayer.players9.musicsamsung.free2018.widgets.ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
                android:padding="0.0dip"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2.0dip"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                app:progressColor="?colorAccent" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/track_info" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Java Class**
[Lint to Java Class](https://pastebin.com/1PpPitUd)

Comment: Sounds like your are doing some expensive operation on creation of the `MainActivity `. You should include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) otherwise there is no way to diagnose the issue.

Comment: I updated the question with link to my java class please check it for any problem.

Comment: Instead of activity_main.xml post your MainActivity.java  .... So that community can help you to solve the problem

Comment: @sandhyasasane I've provided the link MainActivity.java, Please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way... I am not writing it as answer ; which i will delete once he will read it. 
But if followed line by line and after doing same changes it will get resolved too

> Stop coding thousands of lines in your `mainsctivity`

It is not the place where all code and logic and operations goes...!!

> What is mainActivity for then,,,??

As per my knowledge For only 100 lines of code

> What that 100 lines of code should do?

Check android version , if above Marshmallow ask permissions on below do nothing. And start the services on main thread or start the another threads for operations and tasks..!!

### Solution :

1. Make a new project by taking a sample code of navigation project which is given ready made in android studio while creating new project
2. Forget coding. Do not code a single line keep it as it is.
3. Check it over all emulators like 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0
4. It will work and , it must work..!!
5. Now in mainactivity just get the permissions.
6. And whatever your operations needed to perform, perform in background threads.
7. Yes i know you will ask i want to access main ui... too
8. Please see and perform sample codes like this video... Please do not avoid watching it... do not cheat yourself... [Very simple demonstration of performing operations in android projects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QfQE1ayCzf8)
9. Again once it is done , move your code from previous app to this new structure
10. It will take time..., But it the right way of doing it.

Thats. it.

> A i know this is not the answer ..., I know this should not be the error as well

Comment: Don't delete this please. It may not be an answer but it's very helpful to beginners like me.

Comment: @NithisKumar, Well.. Looks you have read it nicely.. Have you seen the video of how exactly background tasks can be performed on main thread without blocking UI?